# Close modal on browser back and then erase the forward state?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I have a form that the user can open as a modal window. I would like to be able to detect when they browse back and close the window.

I've got it working but there are some problems:

```
// in modal.open():
window.history.pushState(null, null);

// in modal.close():
window.history.back();
```

This works with the side effect that they can then browse forward and nothing happens... This is an edge case, it probably doesn't matter too much but it bothers me.

How do I "erase" the current state when browsing back? So they can't go forward to it.

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle, user can not go forward

https://jsfiddle.net/5y6jL0an/

```
history.pushState(null, null, 'no-back-button');
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  history.pushState(null, null, 'no-back-button');
});
```

Comment: This method leaves the opposite problem. Now instead of a useless forward history, there is a useless back history. I.e., if they want to browse back they'll have to hit it twice.